# Split String with Javascript to an JS Object or JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I want to create an JavaScript object or Json from a string, which is separated by **;**.
So I can split the string at the **;**  after that I have to split at the **:** to create the variable name  and the variable value. But how do I do that?

The string:

```
"MT"[1]:"111";"Medium"[1]:"AAA";"Medium"[2]:"BBB";"Medium"[3]:"CCC";"Medium"[4]:"DDD";"bar"[1]:"24";"bar"[2]:"1,5";"bar"[3]:"3";"bar"[4]:"7,5";"S_Id"[1]:"555";"S_Nr"[1]:"666"
```

The result have to look like this:

```
MT[1] = “111”
Medium[1] = “AAA”
Medium[2]=”BBB” 
Medium[3]=”BBB” 
Medium[4]=”BBB” 
bar[1]=“24“
…
```

The goal is to have access to the variable with index and the variable value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're splitting a string, that will return a string not an array, you need a JsonParser to do what you want, Or code your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var x = '"MT"[1]:"111";"Medium"[1]:"AAA";"Medium"[2]:"BBB";"Medium"[3]:"CCC";"Medium"[4]:"DDD";"bar"[1]:"24";"bar"[2]:"1,5";"bar"[3]:"3";"bar"[4]:"7,5";"S_Id"[1]:"555";"S_Nr"[1]:"666"';

var obj = {};

var y = x.split(';');

y.forEach(function(itm){
  var z = itm.split(':');
   var key = z[0].split('[')[0].replace(/"/g, '');
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = [];
  }
  obj[key].push(z[1].replace(/"/g, ''));
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Oh thank you! But now, I'm to stupid to get access to the values. alert(obj["Medium"][1])  the result is "undefined"

Comment: This log output without problem: `console.log(obj["Medium"][1]);` . look https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyNgvG @InFlames82

Answer (score 0):

Try (string in s, r is result object - you cahn change it by change `b=r` in map parameter)

```
s.split(";").map( (x,i,a,b=r,y=x.match(/"(.*?)"\[(.*?)]:"(.*)"/),v=b[y[1]]||[]) => {v[y[2]]=y[3];b[y[1]]=v} );
```

```js
let s = '"MT"[1]:"111";"Medium"[1]:"AAA";"Medium"[2]:"BBB";"Medium"[3]:"CCC";"Medium"[4]:"DDD";"bar"[1]:"24";"bar"[2]:"1,5";"bar"[3]:"3";"bar"[4]:"7,5";"S_Id"[1]:"555";"S_Nr"[1]:"666"'


let r={}  // result

s.split(";").map( (x,i,a,b=r,y=x.match(/"(.*?)"\[(.*?)]:"(.*)"/),v=b[y[1]]||[]) => {v[y[2]]=y[3];b[y[1]]=v} );

Object.assign(this, r) // copy fields from result to "this" (for direct access from JS)

console.log("MT[1] =", MT[1] );
console.log("Medium[1] =", Medium[1] );
console.log("Medium[2]=", Medium[2] );
console.log("Medium[3]=", Medium[3] );
console.log("Medium[4]=", Medium[4] );
console.log("bar[1]=", bar[1] );
```